# Proving an example of the Substitution Rule Rigorously

Tags: calculus, integration, substitution

The statement trying to be proved:

Let $f(x)$ be a continous function, show that for any $a > 0$, we must have

$$\int_{0}^a x^3f(x^2)dx-\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{a^2} xf(x)dx=0$$

So my approach is this:

Let,

$$u=x^2$$
$$du=2x\cdot dx$$
$$dx=\frac{du}{2x}$$

Substituting $u$ to $\int_{0}^a x^3f(x)dx$,

$$\int_{0}^a x^3f(x)dx$$

$$=\int_{0^2}^{a^2} x^3f(u)\frac{du}{2x}$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0^2}^{a^2} x^2f(u)du$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0^2}^{a^2} uf(u)du$$

Since the choice of variable is arbitrary,
$$=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0^2}^{a^2} xf(x)dx$$

Hence,
$$\int_{0}^a x^3f(x)dx=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0^2}^{a^2} xf(x)dx$$
$$\int_{0}^a x^3f(x)dx-\frac{1}{2}\int_{0^2}^{a^2} xf(x)dx=0$$

Are the steps that I used valid? I am particularly concerned whether my statement "Since the choice of variable is arbitrary" is correct or no.

I also think that the steps I use are not rigorous enough. Is there perhaps any other rigorous approach to this problem?

Comment: Your argument is wrong, and the statement it probably wrong as well.  Perhaps the first integral should be $\int_{0}^a x^3f(x^2)dx$?

Comment: @MartinR, yes, its fixed now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are the steps that I used valid?

No. You cannot substitute only *some* instances of $x$ by $u$, i.e. this $\int_{0^2}^{a^2} x^3f(u)\frac{du}{2x}$ makes no sense. And even if you think of $x$ as $u^{1/2}$ in that term then
$$
\frac{1}{2}\int_{0^2}^{a^2} x^2f(u)du =\frac{1}{2}\int_{0^2}^{a^2} u^2f(u)du
$$
becomes wrong.

A correct proof via the substitution rule is simple and straightforward: the function $g: [0, a] \to [0, a^2]$, $g(x) = x^2$ has a continuous derivative, therefore is
$$
 \int_0^a x^3 f(x^2) \, dx  = \frac 12 \int_0^a g(x) f(g(x)) g'(x) \, dx
= \frac 12 \int_0^{a^2} u f(u) \, du.
$$
Or if you prefer the $u = x^2$, $du = 2x dx$ notation:
$$
 \int_0^a x^3 f(x^2) \, dx  = \frac 12 \int_0^a x^2 f(x^2) \, 2x  dx
= \frac 12 \int_0^{a^2} u f(u) \, du.
$$
(Note that there is no need to divide by $x$, which would be problematic at $x=0$.)

> I am particularly concerned whether my statement "Since the choice of variable is arbitrary" is correct or no.

That is correct:
$$
\frac 12 \int_0^{a^2} u f(u) \, du = \frac 12 \int_0^{a^2} x f(x) \, dx
$$
because the naming of the integration variable does not matter.

Comment: I understand your proof, thank you! The part where you mention that I only change some instance of x, there was a really bad typo from my part there that makes it confusing. If then I say that $=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0^2}^{a^2} x^2f(u)du$ =
$=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0^2}^{a^2} uf(u)du$, would this be now correct?

Comment: @Willow: Don't mix original and substituted integration variables as in $\frac{1}{2}\int_{0^2}^{a^2} x^2f(u)du$. With some goodwill it can be understood, but it is not standard and error-prone. In addition your approach has a problem at $x=0$ (division by zero).

Answer (score 1):

You can substitute from the previous destination for extra rigour. Let $x=u^2$, so $dx=2udu$

$$\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{a^2} xf(x)dx$$

$$=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{a} u^2f(u^2)2udu$$

$$=\int_{0}^{a} u^3f(u^2)du$$